# Why was a (seemingly) relevant, non-offensive comment removed?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

The comments on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14482794/324364) question were all wiped recently.

Most of the comments revolved around a discussion of why the question was receiving down votes with the OP (and myself and one other user). While that portion of the comments never quite descended into anything particularly nasty, I completely understand why it would be removed, once it had run it's course (not relevant, putting our "best foot forward", etc.).

However, the first comment (if I recall correctly) by Ben Bolker was actually related to the question itself, regarding the usefulness of alternate visualization techniques. It was (I thought) a useful contribution to the question, that didn't quite rise to the level of  an answer.

I assume that some/all of these comments were flagged. Was the removal of that first comment by Ben simply an oversight, and if so can that one comment be reinstated?

Comment: There is a 'obsolete' option for flagging, the mods usually then clean out the thread of comments. I'd expect Ben's comment to have been an oversight.

Comment: I think the mods have two options: delete comments one at a time, or clear all the comments from a post.  They probably just went with the second option.

Comment: If I am correct, there are no options to reinstate a comment once it is deleted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Comments cannot be resurrected or undeleted. Think of them as the bill posters slathered across building sites for upcoming gigs. There to impart small nuggets of whatever glue gum pasting they need to and gone the next week.

But don't think of them as sacrosanct, needing to stick around for all of wikidumpenternity.

A useful comment better serves the community when it is worked into a relevant post.

Mods have the option of purging the entire comment train and will do so when the weight of keeping one around against countable others is just not worth bothering.

The moral of the story is: Don't leave good stuff in the comments. That's not where you put that onion ring.

Comment: "That's not where you put that onion ring." Classic.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Irony of ironies, Ben just re-added a new version of his comment as a comment, rather than including it in his answer. ;)

Comment: +1, a thousand times.  When a person has to scroll through comments to see relevant information, we've already lost.  That is precisely why Stack Overflow was created: To have the useful content be easy to find (hence why this is a Q&A site, and not a forum).  It's not easy to find if you have to read a dozen comments to get to the gem.  Put it in a post if you want it to be around for eternity.