# Comment status: are they 'disposable'?

Tags: discussion, comments

I didn't know the comments were 'disposable' as I thought they were also contributions covered by the CC-by-sa license. What are their status??

See comment by @joran there [Specifying directly factor levels and sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048544/r-specifying-directly-factor-levels-and-sizes)

Comment: FWIW, you can read more [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/164376) about deleted content.

Comment: Ok, so I will prefer answers to comments from now on as suggested here and there http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164783/why-was-a-seemingly-relevant-non-offensive-comment-removed?rq=1
Thanks for all your inputs ... and comments ..

Answer (score 5):

Comments are second-class citizens. They didn't even exist when SO was created.

The moderators routinely destroy irrelevant comments, so don't put any important stuff in the comments; put it in answers instead.

> I thought they were also contributions covered by the CC-by-sa license

How does that change anything? Questions and answers can be deleted by users with over 10000 reputation; comments can also be deleted (only by moderators).

Comment: That is important as if you can derive work, it doesn't mean you can just destroy other people content. In fact, this aks the question of the ownership, copyright of the whole content around here.

Comment: @green Wait, what? Once you post something on SO, it is no longer yours. You don't own it any more. You can't copyright your posts - they are all CC licensed.

Comment: If it's not mine, does it make theirs (ppl with 10k+ rep) to dispose of? BTW, depending on the country, the content ownership can't be transferred like that. Anyway CC is for creative commons, not destructive 10k+ rep.

Comment: @greendiod Stack Exchange is in New York, so only US law applies. As well, just because you own rights to something doesn't mean the network you're hosting it on is obligated in any way to keep it around. It's *your* responsibility to keep copies of anything important you don't want to disappear.

Comment: Clarification: when questions and answers are deleted they are still viewable by users with >10K rep (you need a direct link though because they don't show up in lists or search results). When comments are deleted they are not viewable by anyone except diamond mods (and staff of course).

Comment: @Doorknob There is no actual transfer of ownership when content is posted to Stack Exchange. You release it to Stack Exchange under the CC license and the TOS, but you retain ownership of the copyright. One might say "you don't own it anymore" in a rhetorical sense -- you no longer have complete control over how it is used -- but in a legal sense, you *do* still own it. CC licensing is a *use* of your copyright, not an alternative to it.

Comment: Of course, moderators should not be destroying comments that contain *important stuff*, so there should be little risk in putting important stuff in comments if it won't fit as an answer.

Comment: @CodyGray It's can be difficult to spot that one important comment in the sea of "me too"'s "what have you tried"'s etc. so if you want to say something truly important make sure it's in a question or answer.

Comment: @greendiod ownership of a comment does not give you the right to impose an obligation on **anyone else** to host your content. So if you generate a creative work in a comment, it remains yours: but there is no obligation on Stack Exchange, or anyone else, to host it for you.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I don't want to impose any obligation on anyone else. But you're nipicking here, so why Stack Exchange has offered to host any content at all in the first place?? Aren't they the first to profit from other people freely given time and content????

Comment: @JeremyBanks Yeah, it's the true meaning and intent of the CC license but apparently, a few people here see it otherwise.